# Stylus +cache not allowing formatted strings

Tags: caching, media-queries, stylus

I don't understand why something like this occurs based off [this](http://kizu.ru/en/issues/new-stylus-features/) article

```
+media(s("'(min-width: %spx)'", $max-padding)) // doesn't work
+media('(max-width: ' + $max-padding + 'px)') // sloppy but works
```

The top compiles to the correct thing in the command line, but the +cache doesn't accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `s()` outputs `literal` token instead of a `string` one. The most simple way of fixing it would be to ensure the `$condition` inside a `media` mixin is a string, so you can add

```
$condition = '' + $condition
```

at the start of it, and then use the `s()` the way you use it, but without the extra quotes:

```
+media(s("(min-width: %spx)", $max-padding))
```

Also, a hint: there is a `%` operator that works almost exactly like `s()`, but can be cleaner, plus the `apply_media_cache` mixin is smart enough, so you could omit the braces too:

```
+media("min-width: %spx" % $max-padding)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and very nice feature!